# When using asynchronous calls/completion handlers in a class function whats the best way to update variables in my controller?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

My app uses Parse for the backend and I have lots of asynchronous calls with completion handlers all over my app. Right now my app is a bit of a mess because I have repeated functions everywhere to get/set values in Parse, this is because I can't figure out how to put the function in my class and then be able to update whatever I'm doing in my controller.

Example: I have a User class and the user can have several associated Car objects. Ideally I think I would like a class method like "User.getCars" that I can use all over my app but instead I declare the below function in several different places.

```
var cars = [ParseCar]()

func getCar(){
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Car")
    query.whereKey("owner", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
    {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) cars.")
                for object in objects! {
                    self.cars.append(object as! ParseCar)

                self.cars = objects! as! [ParseCar]
                print("cars array is: \(self.cars)")
                self.checkNumberOfCars()
                }
            } else {

                showAlertPopup(self, titleText: "Error", messageText: "Network request to get users car failed")

                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
    }
}
```

So I have 2 specific questions...

1. My "cars" array is in the view controller and I want to update it with the results from Parse. If I were to put the "getCars" function in my "User" class I could do User.getCars which would call the getCars method but how do I append the results back to my "cars" array? I can't return anything from the completion handler so there's no way to pass it back, is there? and I can't set a variable at the beginning of "getCars" which gets updated in the completion handler then return it because the return will happen before the completion handler runs.
2. If I get a set of data back I have a function in my controller "checkNumberofCars" which counts the objects in the "cars" array and if there are multiple it triggers a popup so the user can select which car they want to work with. Obviously I can't call that function from inside the class method since its declared in the controller so how do I communicate back to my controller that once I have the set of cars I then want to run the "checkNumberofCars" function?

Any other advice on handling this general situation would be awesome!

Comment: You should encapsulate your data in a data model class (so this model class would have your cars array, the view controller would have a reference to the data model). The data model can either be a singleton or a single reference passed between your view controllers (dependency injection). You can use NSNotification to allow interested objects (such as view controllers) to subscribe to data model updates.

Comment: " I can't return anything from the completion handler". Yes you can, they can take parameters just like a method does.

Comment: @Paulw11 - So I have file A with my object class which defines the properties of my object, file B which defines any data structures I want to work with such as the cars array, and file C which is my view controller which is hooked up to the UI and takes tells the model what the UI wants to do and vice versa? Sorry, i know this is iOS dev 101... thought I had a better handle on it. I guess I'm combining the model and the controller? any suggested further reading on the topic?

Comment: Yes, You could have a `Car` class, a `Garage` class (that contained an array of `Car`s) and then the view controller would have a reference to an instance of `Garage`.  Car/Garage are the model in MVC and the UIViewController, is the controller.

Comment: So I have a User class and a Car class, and to simplify representing a User with several Cars I should create a Garage class (or whatever) to hold that collection of cars? Should basically everything I work with in the VC be represented as a class? Just tyring to get a sense of how I should be thinking about this... i guess I assumed it wouldn't make sense to have a Garage type class as it would only have one property (an array of Cars) and the function to get those cars from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to provide data from an asynchronous operation is to use a closure. This is just a function which your code calls when it's done. For example:

```
func getCar(completion: (ParseCar) -> Void) {
    ....
    let someCar: ParseCar = ....
    completion(someCar)
}
```

To manage complexity, it is often effective to decompose the problem into simpler pieces. There is no right answer, here is one suggestion:

1. Encapsulate the web service code into a class.
2. Encapsulate the common view controller code into a class.
3. Call the encapsulated code from each of your view controllers where it's used.

Your API for fetching cars could look like this:

```
class CarsService {

    func getCars(completion: ([ParseCar]?, NSError?) -> Void){

        let query = PFQuery(className:"Car")
        query.whereKey("owner", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let objects = objects {
                let output = [ParseCar]()
                for object in objects {
                    output.append(object as! ParseCar)
                }
                completion(output, nil)
            } else {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The API could be used like this:

```
let service = CarsService()
service.getCars() { cars, error in
    if let cars = cars {
        self.countCars(cars)
    }
    else if let error = error {
        self.showCarsError(error)
    }
}
```

You could go one step further and combine `countCars` and the error handling into another reusable controller:

```
class CarsController {
    weak var viewController: UIViewController?
    var service: CarsService

    init(viewController: UIViewController, service: CarsService) {
        self.viewController = viewController
        self.service = service
    }

    func getCar(completion: (ParseCar?) -> Void) {

        service.getCars() { cars, error in
            if let cars = cars {
                self.countCars(cars, completion: completion)
            }
            else if let error = error {
                self.showError(error)
            }
        }
    }

    private func countCars(cars: [ParseCar], completion: (ParseCar?) -> Void) {
        // Count cars and display prompt, e.g:
        if cars.count == 0 {
            completion(nil)
        }
        else if cars.count == 1 {
            completion(cars.first)
        }
        else {
            // Create UI to select car.
            // Call completion callback with selected car:
            completion(selectedCar)
        }
    }

    private func showError(error: NSError) {
        let alertViewController = // Create view controller...
        viewController.presentViewController(alertViewController)
    }
}
```

It would then be relatively easy to reuse this functionality in multiple view controllers:

```
let carsService = CarsService()
carsController = CarsController(viewController: self, service: service)
carsController.getCar() { car in
    print("Selected car = \(car)")
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Been playing around with this structure and man its going to make life easier.

Comment: This finally gave me some insight in *best* practices. Now I can finally make my project a bit more accessible. Thanks for the clear and comprehensive answer.